# Problem in defining object of a structure inside itself

Tags: c, struct

This works:

```
struct LD__32
{
   struct LD__32 *ld;
};
```

But this doesn't:

```
struct LD_32
{
   struct LD_32 ld;
};
```

Why is this?
I was compiling it as c++ code as pmg guessed. edited

Comment: Are you compiling your code as C++? In C, without a `typedef` in scope, the type name is `struct LD__32`. Try printing the value of `sizeof 'a'`: if it's not 1, you're ok; if it's 1 the test is inconclusive (but you're probably compiling as C++)

Comment: @pmg: or an easier test, print the value of `__cplusplus` (as a `long`). On no conforming C99 compiler, and on no known compiler of any other kind of C, will that be defined.

Comment: Thanks for that @Steve. I don't know C++. Are all (Standard) C++ compiler implementations guaranteed to define the `__cplusplus` symbol?

Comment: @pmg: yes, the C++98 and C99 standards co-ordinated. So C99 implementations are forbidden to define it, and C++ implementations must define it to the value `199711L` (or smaller values for pre-standard, non-conforming implementations). It will be given a new value in C++0x.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A structure in C cannot contain a member with incomplete type.

In the latter case you can't have `LD_32 ld;` defined inside the `LD_32` definition because the struct `LD_32` is not already defined at that point.

Check out `constaints` on structure in C

Section 6.7.2.1/2

> **A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type (hence,
>   a structure shall not contain an instance of itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance of itself)**, except that the last member of a structure with more than one named member may  have  incomplete  array  type;  such  a  structure  (and  any union  containing,  possibly recursively, a member that is such a structure) shall not be a member of a structure or an element of an array.

Answer (score 2):

Think about

```
sizeof(struct LD_32)
```

Comment: In this case it could be 1. Or any number, really. It's when there are other struct members that this argument becomes conclusive.

Comment: I think it's conclusive enough when a compile-time expression like sizeof() can have any value :-).

Comment: I mean that the implementation could choose any number, just as it has to choose a number for the size of an empty struct. 1 is the obvious choice. This struct does not present a size-related contradiction in the way that, say `struct LD { LD ld; int x;}` presents a contradiction. Consider that `sizeof(int)` is another example that can be any number the implementation chooses. In the case of `int` of course some choices are easier to implement than others, but the fact that the implementation has freedom isn't a problem as far as the standard is concerned...

Comment: There is no such thing as "an empty struct" in C. And the fact that all objects have a representation as a `char` array overlaid with the object, together with the non-existence of zero-length arrays, implies to me that zero-size objects cannot exist in C.

Comment: @R..: yes, fair point. "just as a C++ compiler has to choose a size for an empty struct", then. In C++, classes can have no data members (hence "empty"), but still are not zero-size. My point is, requiring implementations to make arbitrary choices is *not* a show-stopper as far as writing standards is concerned. Pretty much any other example would have illustrated Philipp's point by being logically impossible (which is a show-stopper).

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a recursive and infinite definition.  Think about it.

Comment: Check @Nawaz answer for a proper explaination.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct LD_32
{
   LD_32 ld;
};
```

In this situation, how would you expect the compiler to determine the size of  the struct `LD_32`.

Size of a struct is determined by calculating the sum of the size of all the members, plus some padding.

So even if there is no padding, the size of this struct `LD_32` would be equal to size of it's member which is `LD_32` itself, that means,

```
sizeof(LD_32) = size of member { size(LD_32) = size of member { size(LD_32) = size of member { size(LD_32) = ...    ... } } } } } }
```

In short, the size cannot be calculated, because the size depends on itself which is unknown.

So the size is indeterminate.