# C - Field has incomplete type

Tags: c, struct

In the below representation,

```
struct Cat{
  char *name;
  struct Cat mother;
  struct Cat *children;
};
```

---

Compiler gives below error for second field, but not third field,

```
 error: field ‘mother’ has incomplete type
   struct Cat mother;
              ^
```

---

How to understand this error?

Comment: [Problem in defining object of a structure inside itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329570/problem-in-defining-object-of-a-structure-inside-itself)

Comment: You have a recursive `struct` definition.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The error means that you try and add a member to the `struct` of a type that isn't fully defined yet, so the compiler cannot know its size in order to determine the objects layout.

In you particular case, you try and have `struct Cat` hold a complete object of itself as a member (the `mother` field). That sort of infinite recursion in type definition is of course impossible.

Nevertheless, structures can contain pointers to other instances of themselves. So if you change your definition as follows, it will be a valid `struct`:

```
struct Cat{
  char *name;
  struct Cat *mother;
  struct Cat *children;
};
```

Comment: so that means, `struct Cat children[10]` will also be not allowed. What is recursive in type definition here?

Comment: @user1787812 - Correct. However `struct Cat *children[10]` (not the `*`) is allowed. An array of *pointers* is perfectly okay.

Comment: @user1787812 - The recursion is in the type containing itself **completely** as a member.

Comment: Why `struct Cat *children` member does not make the type recursive?

Comment: @user1787812 - because it's a pointer. You don't need the complete type definition to declare a pointer to it.

Comment: So, Do you mean infinite recursive type definition, in the sense, that type checker(in compiler) tries to know the type of `mother` and gets into infinite recursive calls?

Comment: @user1787812 - It doesn't go into recursive calls. It stops and emits an error because it recognizes the type contains itself as member.